# i am not able to tap on textfield it's keep refreshing when i click on the textfield

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

i am not able to tap on textfield it's keep refreshing when i click on the textfield.

try all the solution which i get from stackoverflow but still not solving this problem..

i am sharing full project github link.

This is my project link https://github.com/Akash-ptl/your_service
[image: This is the problem i get]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime the UI gets refreshed, the **snapshot.connectionState** is set to **ConnectionState.waiting**. Therefore, the **CircularProgressIndicator()** gets displayed.

You can try this by doing a **setState()** somewhere in your code.

**Solution:**
Just wait for the connectionState only one time when you load the page.

[Here is the Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkIkg.png)

Comment: solved my error with tusing switch case method for future builder...

Answer (score 0):

read this https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility
in a nut shell you need to change your AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<activity
       ...
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
```

...

don't set it to  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Depends on your requirement though. Read the documentation above.